# ggplot pretty scale function not displaying max value

Tags: r, ggplot2

My maximum `pretty` axis break value is not displayed in my plot. Specifically, the rightmost break value 25 is not displayed in `ggplot` axis.

```
breaks = pretty(1:23)
> breaks
#[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25

p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(1:23)) 

breaks = pretty(1:23)
> breaks
#[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25

p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(1:23))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the limits too:
`p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(1:23), limits = c(0, 25))`

Comment: Or `limits = c(min(breaks), max(breaks))` assuming you assign `breaks <- pretty(1:23)`